# Identify a product page via DOM in Shopify

Tags: javascript, dom, shopify, shopify-app

Does a Shopify store have anything within the DOM which only appears when viewing a product page, rather than another page type like a collection?

I've viewed the source code of a few different Shopify stores but cannot find anything consistent thus far.

I was looking for something like a body class or ID etc to hook in to with something I'm writing.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The URL contains the path /products/. Other than that, there are zero requirements to render any elements pertaining to products as a thing.